# Target copies evaluation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a scenario where I am building a framework for iOS, however I am trying to build a dev and QA versions of this file by changing the end point in a dedicated file. I was in impression if I could make different targets of such frameworks which have dedicated url's, and packet it together maybe? I am little confused in such scenario to move forward, and don't want to messup my architecture of the project, hence wanted to get some idea what might be a better option to move forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using preprocessor macros feature instead e.g.:

```
#define QA 1
#define DEV 0

#define ENV QA

#if (ENV == QA)
NSString *const url = @"http://example.com/qa";
#elif (ENV == DEV)
NSString *const url = @"http://example.com/dev";
#endif
```

in my opinion that is an easier way to deal with several environments

you can take it one step further and define QA and DEV in build settings and not in the code

Comment: I found a good tutorial, just to over come this situation. http://www.codeworth.com/blog/mobile/ios-distinguish-between-targets-using-pre-processor-targets/